# What is the ideal XML Schema for a Tree Structure with nested Nodes?

Tags: xml, xsd, tree, taxonomy

I need to design a XML-Schema which should work with something like this tree:

[image: Attack Taxonomy Tree Structure]

It's the first time i have to design XML and i don't find something useful for my problem. I tried it with enumerations, but i think that's not the way to do it.

Is it done with a recursion?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this Schema: https://cwe.mitre.org/data/xsd/cwe_schema_v3.0.xsd

Perfect Structure for this kind of Tree.